# how to create a class automatically from datatable

Tags: c#, sql, class, serialization, datatable

I know there's a cleaner way to do this than the way I am. Basically, I retrieve a datatable from my sql database. I now want to have that information in a class that is globally accessible. I don't want to have to go through each column like so: txtFirstName.Text = dt[0].ToString(). I want to create a "User" class, and assign txtFirstName.Text = User.FirstName. BUT, I don't want to manually map dt[0] to FirstName, and dt[1] to LastName...I want the object to be created automagically! Or, at least once the class is created, and the elements match the names of the dt columns, the mapping should happen automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use Linq to SQL? I like it alot.

Once you draw out your tables you can then create a separate partial .cs class file for individual tables in this case. DO NOT EDIT THE GENERATED CODE :) If you saved your dbml file in lets say "App_Code/Linq_customer/" Folder and mapped a table you named "Customer", your class may look like this (untested code):

```
using System.Linq;

namespace Linq_customer
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public static Customer GetCustomerByID(int customerID, CustomerDataContext dc)
        {

            return (from s0 in dc.Customers
                   where s0.customerID== customerID
                   select s0).firstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then from your page or other class do something like:

```
using Linq_customer;
...
CustomerDataContext dc = new CustomerDataContext() //(Generated data context)
Customer myCustomerDude = Customer.GetCustomerByID(5, dc);
if(myCustomerDude == null) return error..
txtFirstName.Text = myCustomerDude.firstName;
```

Optionally if you wanted to create a new user:

```
myCustomerDude = new Customer();
```

And saving any new info is fairly easy too:

...

```
myCustomerDude.City = txtCity.Text;
myCustomerDude.favoriteSlogan = "I believe in Science";
dc.Customers.insertOnSubmit(myCustomerDude); //If not already existing, if is already in table then omit this line.
dc.submitChanges();
```

Comment: Looking at Linq to SQL, I see how I can assign datasources. But what about accessing individual entities in the dataclasses?   `code`var CustomersQuery = from customers in northwindDataContext1.Customers
                      where customers.City == CityTextBox.Text
                      select customers;
customerBindingSource.DataSource = CustomersQuery;

Comment: How do you deal with edit & continue and Linq? I've found that I cannot edit a method with a linq call in it, and that's annoying!

Comment: while debugging, i can't make changes to a method if it contains LINQ. I have to restart debugging. VS 2010 C# Winforms App

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5218/discussion-between-toddbfisher-and-user948060)

Comment: How do you deal with views and stored procs and LINQ? Is LINQ supposed to replace those, or is there a way to use them together?

Answer (score 3):

You're basically asking for an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping) (object relational mapping).  Two of them that come with .NET are [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).  Others also exist, such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).  The topic is pretty involved, so you may want to investigate all of your options and select which would work best in your scenario.

Comment: I've used Linq alot, are there major advantages of Entity Framework over linq or are they about the same?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the FCL? [*The Base Class Library (BCL) is literally that, the base. It contains basic, fundamental types like System.String and System.DateTime . The Framework Class Library (FCL) is the wider library that contains the totality: ASP.NET, WinForms, the XML stack, ADO.NET and more. You could say that the FCL includes the BCL.Apr 30, 2009*](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=.net+bcl)

Answer (score 2):

Don't roll your own. It's far too much work. Use LINQ-to-SQL. The command-line tool `sqlmetal` will convert an existing schema into a C# file that you can use directly in LINQ queries. As a matter of fact, I was doing precisely this for our FogBugz database when this question popped up:

```
sqlmetal /server:<our-server> /database:fogbugz /views /functions /sprocs /code:fogbugz.cs
```

Comment: DO you have run this each time the schema changes?

Comment: Yes. You may want to integrate it into your project's pre-build step. I find it best to place the data model file that sqlmetal produces into its own project so that all your projects can share it, and add the pre-build step to that.

Comment: and, how do you change databases, ie dev vs prod? Do you just generate a new file with the new connection info, or change the connection string in your project?

Comment: @user948060: The connection string isn't part of the generated code (or if it is, I don't use it). Pass a `SqlConnection` to the constructor of the generated context class.

Answer (score 2):

you can use reflection,like this:
I'm sorry the comments are chinaese
you can invoke like this: `ConvertDataRowToModel(User object,dt,0);`

```
    #region 根据反射机制将dataTable中指定行的数据赋给obj对象
    /// <summary>
    /// 根据反射机制将dataTable中指定行的数据赋给obj对象
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">obj对象</param>
    /// <param name="dataTable">dataTable</param>
    /// <param name="rowIndex">指定行</param>
    public static void ConvertDataRowToModel(object obj, DataTable dataTable, int rowIndex)
    {
        //指定行不存在
        if (dataTable.Rows.Count < (rowIndex + 1))
        {
            throw new Exception("指定行不存在!");
        }

        //DataTable列为空!
        if (dataTable.Columns.Count < 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("DataTable列为空!");
        }

        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pInfos = type.GetProperties();

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pInfos.Length; j++)
                {
                    //全部转换为小写的作用是防止数据库列名的大小写和属性的大小写不一致
                    if (dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower() == pInfos[j].Name.ToLower())
                    {
                        PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty(pInfos[j].Name);  //obj某一属性对象

                        object colValue = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][i]; //DataTable 列值

                        #region 将列值赋给object属性
                        if (!Comm_Object.ObjectIsNull(colValue))
                        {
                            if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.String")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToString(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int32")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Int64")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt64(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Single")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToSingle(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Double")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDouble(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Decimal")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDecimal(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Char")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToChar(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Boolean")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToBoolean(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(colValue), null);
                            }
                            //可空类型
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDateTime(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt64(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt64(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDecimal(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else if (pInfos[j].PropertyType.FullName == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
                            {
                                pInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToDecimal(colValue), null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception("属性包含不支持的数据类型!");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pInfo.SetValue(obj, null, null);
                        }
                        #endregion

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ORM which will map your database tables to objects. Other options include

1. Create a T4 template to read from the database and create your objects with "mapping" code. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)
2. Create the classes and use AutoMapper to map the IDataReader to your object.